# Does wordpress automatically no-index no-follow pages that are deleted?

Tags: wordpress, seo

Does wordpress automatically no-index no-follow pages that are deleted? Or do I have to manually do this myself?

Also, does WordPress automatically redirect deleted pages too? Or is this something I need to do myself?

Comment: How can WordPress apply those rules to pages that no longer exist?

Comment: I thought it may still keep some remnant of them in their database, it would seem to make better sense than me having to manually redirect any deleted pages to prevent 404 accumulation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have been using wordpress for quite a sometime now. I don't really think anything like that happens. If you want to delete any post/page, you will have to long in with your admin username and pass and do it manually. That is the only way to delete any page/post.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are asking about whether the indexing in search engines such as google and bing still remain after you have deleted the pages/posts in WorPress.

If search engines managed to index your page/post before you deleted it then yes will most likely show up until the search engines decides to re-indexes your website. Not sure about other search engines but Google Webmasters tool has a feature called "Remove URLs" where you can manually specify to google which URLs to stop indexing.

Alternatively you will have to do 301 redirects in your .htaccess file if you are running on an apache server to redirect the urls of the deleted to your home page or find some redirect plugins for wordpress.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, they won't. You have to create custom re-direction to redirect them on a suitable page. You can do these re-directions in htaccess file or use a plugin to do so. Or you can use tools given in google webmaster tool to remove the url from their index server.

You can get more information here : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you delete or remove any page from wordpress website/blog then wordpress will automatically redirect it to 404 error page. if you want to get it redirect to another page then you have to manually do it.

Hope this will help you!